# How to import somebody else document from GD to my Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, import

I have a link to somebody else GD document. I would like to copy/import it to my GD so for example, if that person deletes the file I would have a "local" copy.

I can copy&paste entire document, but I would like to know if there is a way to actually import the file, so I could be sure the content was not altered by mistake.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the document
2. Go the `File` menu and select `Make a copy...`
3. Give the document a new name

   - You can optionally share it with the same people as the original
   - Comments are not copied
4. Click "OK"

If you only have a link, because the author use the "Publish to the web..." tool, simply follow the link beneath the document to Google Drive, log in (if necessary), and you'll see the document in the list of your documents. You can then use the steps above.

If you can't or won't log in to Google Drive, then your option is to copy and paste.

Comment: Thank you, in source document there is document itself with header and footer bars -- header contains document title, while footer contains link do GD and link for reporting GD abuse. In any of those "sections" there is no menu.

Comment: And when you follow the link to Google Drive is your document there? My answer assumes that the document is shared. What you're describing seems to be something else.

Comment: I see. Someone has used the "Publish to the web..." option. If you follow the link to Google Drive from that, it should open Google Drive and you'll see the document there. Then you can follow the steps above.

Comment: Thank you again. The link in the footer bar is directing to general GD, so what I see after clicking it is my GD, with my files, etc. And I don't have in my GD any File menu. All I see is Create/Upload button, list of my files, filters (shared by me, shared by someone else, etc), and settings.

Comment: You need to open the document from within Google Drive. Because you followed the link it should be there in your list of documents.

Comment: Thank you, but no, it is not, because the link from the footer is -- https://docs.google.com/. So it is generic address, so the effect is exactly the same if I would enter my GD from bookmarks, from fresh start.

Comment: I tested it. I took the link and opened a different browser, where I was not logged in. I logged in using a different Google account that didn't have any Drive documents. Once I got logged in, there, lo and behold, was the shared document.

Comment: I am out of the ideas what is going on. I cannot share the link, because I've got it from registered-only course, but the form is like this: https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1y...

Comment: @AʟE. how to do that with the Android app? I only have this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwPIpgeJ2AdnUGUzVGJuak5abDg/view

Comment: @user2284570: That's a separate question you should ask at [android.se].

Comment: @AʟE. : which is something I did http://android.stackexchange.com/q/159348/87784

Answer (score -1):

Copy the key from the public doc's URL, open one of your own docs and replace the key with the key you copied from the public doc.

Comment: Could you expand on your answer a little - which "key", and how to "replace" it?